# What's the file limit for file upload? Why is any error missing?

Tags: support, asking-questions

When uploading large images the upload window get's stuck. What is the file limit for a image file? Why don't I get an error then upload fails (XHR itself is not returning anything)?

Comment: Have you tried hitting the add picture or upload button a few times? This usually unsticks it for me.

Comment: It's stuck after the upload starts. I tried to upload it several times. Only drastical decrease of resolution has helped.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how large was the picture we are talking about? This question might also fit [meta.se] or maybe there is already a question and answer for this.

Comment: I failed to succeed with anything over 1.5MB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[10MB is the maximum](https://imgur.com/faq#size)

> The maximum non-animated file size you can upload is 10MB. However, if the image is over 1MB then it will automatically be compressed or resized to 1MB, for better viewing on the net. The maximum animated file size (both GIF and PNG) is 2MB.

It might be a network error on your side.

Comment: Network error, that is however not properly caught by javascript.